# Angular-vs-repeat - Unable to scroll to the end when col-md class is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular-vs-repeat for virtual scrolling. I am not able to scroll and see the last data when col-md class is used. Plnkr link  https://plnkr .co/edit/T6Xy3KhuRXBn4MZoLq5K?p=preview

Comment: Actual plnkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/T6Xy3KhuRXBn4MZoLq5K?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred because you didn't add the `latch` option in the `vs-repeat`. You have to set `vs-options="{latch: true}"` to fix this issue.

```
<div class="repeater-container" vs-repeat vs-options="{latch: true}" style="overflow:auto;overflow-anchor: none;">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div style="visibility:hidden">{{item.text}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 bby-padding-top-10">
            <label>{{item.text}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would fix the issue.

Comment: I don't want to use latch option, because I am trying to render more than 5000 records, so performance might get affected if I use latch option

Comment: Any other suggestion to fix this issue

Comment: @aaviss: already someone else has reported this kind of issue in their github page for which they haven't responded yet. I couldn't find any other fix or workaround. Sorry am helpless

Comment: @aaviss: have you tried using vs-repeat="50"? It worked for me.